# swift Mulitpeer Connectivity, canceling invitation using invitation handler

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, multipeer-connectivity

I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/chat-app-swift-tutorial/) for implementing Multipeer connectivity.
In new swift version the default delegate for advertiser is

```
func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: NSData?, invitationHandler: ((Bool, MCSession) -> Void))
{

    self.invitationHandler = invitationHandler

    delegate?.invitationWasReceived(peerID.displayName)
}
```

Earlier the type was `invitationHandler : ((Bool, MCSession!)->Void)!`

As per the current sample when a user declines invitation the call is in this format `self.appDelegate.mpcManager.invitationHandler(false, nil)`

But in new version it doesnt accept `nil` I've tried `self.appDelegate.mpcManager.invitationHandler(false, MCSession())` But that resulted in a crash.

What should I pass in the session to cancel the invitation instead of nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the second parameter of the invitationHandler is not a optional, you must pass in a valid session.

When creating a session you must always pass in a valid MCPeerID. For example:

```
var session: MCSession?
...
session = MCSession(peer: thisPeer)
```

Normally the session should be created once and held as an instance variable of your class.